# Sitefinity 5.X: Override how page title is generated

Tags: sitefinity

http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity/developing-with-sitefinity/override-how-page-title-is-generated.aspx#2050837

I would like to override how the page titles for all pages on a site are generated. The client wants the title to be similar to the site breadcrumb where it is a concatenated list of ancestral page names plus the current page.

I figure that this could be generated when a page is saved but I would have to alter the page title of the current page and all child pages. If I did it this way then if they changed their mind later then I would have to regenerate all of the page names.

Alternatively if I could just override how the page titles are put on the page then I could go get the ancestors and generate the title when the page is viewed by a user.

I lean toward the second but I don't know how to do either. Any ideas?

I am working on 5.X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just cross posting the answer you got on the forums in case anyone is looking here.

The answer from Liam was to refer to this KB article: http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/kb/sitefinity-4-x/globally-overwriting-properties-for-frontend-pages.aspx

which allows you to use global.asax to override the properties globally. pretty slick, I wasn't aware of it!

My suggestion was if you need to do it at the template level to use the **SiteMapBase.GetActualCurrentNode()** method to do it manually.

hope you got it all worked out!